# Installing matlab 2020a on ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: 22.04, matlab, compatibility

I was wondering if i can install matlab 2020a on machine with ubuntu 22.04 lts.
Any one know if that will work or not ?

Comment: Yes you can. Contact MATLAB supports for more details.

Comment: While MATLAB is a proprietary software, you can install `octave`, a free an open source scientific programming compatible with MATLAB syntax. Install it with `sudo apt install octave`. Octave supports majority of MATLAB functions, but it does not have as powerful toolboxes like MATLAB. If you just want to plot/solve differential equations/diagonalize matrices, just go with Octave instead of MATLAB. It is lightweight, as well as free.